# What can make the Framerate drop while CPU is not roofing in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, performance, telerik, frame-rate

We have implemented a drag and drop feature that shows a nice simple representation of what we are dragging.
The drag and drop happens on a view that has a lot of elements
While dragging, the CPU doesn't go to the roof it stays steady below 10 no matter how long or how fast you try to drag the item, but the **framerate drops dramatically** from above 60 to less than 10.

EnableRedraw clearly shows that only the item we drag is being redrawn, not the entire page.

How can I find out what is causing that performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the telerik dragdropmanager, and while dragging, the component is raising events to check if you can drop through 100 elements deep. Solution, until they make that configurable (or that you modify it yourself if you have the source code) is to set IsHitTestVisible to false on heavy elements when you start dragging.

this worked for us :). Dragging is very fluid, even on pages with a lot of elements

Comment: Telerik controls are helpless

Comment: I don't agree, they help us a lot it many situation. The drag and drop manager is really helpful, enables commanding with very nice control over the drag visualizer.
The kind of performance issue we have got here would most probably happen with any drag and drop implementation. We just happen to hit the limit, and needed performance optimizations.